# Downgrade SSRS from 2016 to 2008

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, downgrade

We have 2 environments at work 
one for SSRS 2016 and another for 2008

mistakenly I open one of 2008 reports in VS2016
now I cannot open it in 2008

how can I downgrade an SSRS report opened in 2016 back to 2008?

Comment: I htik a backup is made by default, check the solution folder

Comment: I checked that already but it is in 2016 too!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I managed to do that

1- change the

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition
```

to

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition
```

2- Remove `<ReportSections>` Tag ( not the inner tags, just the parent tag)

3- Remove `<ReportSection>` Tag which will be a child for point number 2 ( again not the inner tags, just the parent tag)

4- Remove `<ReportParametersLayout>` tag and all its children.

5- Remove `<GridLayoutDefinition>` tag and all its children.

Comment: Just to note that `<GridLayoutDefinition>` is within the `<ReportParametersLayout>` in case sombody cannot find it after removing `<ReportParametersLayout>`

Comment: @asmgx thank you so so much, I'm so grateful I feel quite emotional right now :)

Comment: I also had to remove a tag called <PageName> to pass the validation, I was moving from 2016 to 2008

Answer (score 3):

1.Create a new Report Server Project in Visual Studio 2019. To do it, you need to install that [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio).

2.Change file names from rdls to rdl.

3.Add rdl files to project.

4.Change **TargetServerVersion** in project properties to SQL Server 2008

5.Right click on rdl file in Visual studio and select build.

6.New generated rdl file  will be at bin\Release or bin\Debug folder.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the solution and go to Properties.  Change the TargetServerVersion to either "SQL Server 2008" or "SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012 or 2014" depending on your needs.
[image]