# How do I fix the report viewer error in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, rdlc, reportviewer

Error:

> An error occurred during local report processing.
> The definition of the report 'Include\Impresiones\Rport.rdlc' is invalid.
> The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services.
> The report definition may have been created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services schemas.
>
> Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

When I had VS2012 I could edit it without problem but now I updated to VS2019 and when I edited a report and I wanted to show it in the report viewer I get that error, how do I solve it?

In my `web.config` I have:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" 
             type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
        <assemblies>
            <!--<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>-->
            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        </assemblies>
        <buildProviders>
            <!--<add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>-->
            <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID">
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
        <!--<add name="Reserved-ReportViewerWebControl-axd" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />-->
        <!--<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>-->
        <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 12):

**Upgrade Microsoft Reports to support Visual Studio 2019 / 2022**

Run through the following steps to upgrade a project using Microsoft Report Viewer Runtimes 9-13 to Sql Server Reporting Services 14 or 15.

1. Backup Visual Studio solution
2. Check Microsoft Report Designer is installed for [Visual Studio 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001) (min version 15.3.1) or [Visual Studio 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio2022) (min version 17.0.0)
3. Uninstall or manually remove the following assembly references (any versions: 9.0.0.0, 10.0.0.0, 11.0.0.0, 13.0.0.0) from project

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common

4. Install **Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms** OR **Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms** which includes both updated dll's

ASP.NET - For Target Runtime .NET 4.5.2 (14.0.0.0)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms -Version 140.1000.523
```

ASP.NET - For Target Runtime .NET 4.6 and above (15.0.0.0)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms -Version 150.1537.0
```

WinForms - For Target Runtime .NET 4.5.2 (14.0.0.0)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms -Version 140.1000.523
```

WinForms - For Target Runtime .NET 4.6 and above (15.0.0.0)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms -Version 150.1537.0
```

This will install the following assemblies to the project...

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebDesign.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll

5. In ASP.NET - The **App_Code** folder will have new **SqlServerTypes** directory containing  ***Loader.cs***.
   and include package **Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.14.0.314.76**

This folder will also appear in any Library project the package is also installed in.

```
        \SqlServerTypes\
        - Loader.cs or Loader.vb
        - readme.htm
        
        \SqlServerTypes\x64\
        - msvcr120.dll
        - SqlServerSpatial140.dll
        
        \SqlServerTypes\x86\
        - msvcr120.dll
        - SqlServerSpatial140.dll
```

6. If the **App_Code** directory is configured for VB.NET, a new VB class should be added called [***Loader.vb***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229793/how-to-use-dllimport-in-vb-net/50632100#50632100) and the autogenerated ***Loader.cs*** can be removed from App_Code\SqlServerTypes.

   ```
       Imports System
       Imports System.IO
       Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

       Namespace SqlServerTypes
           Public Class Utilities

               <DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
               Public Shared Function LoadLibrary(ByVal libname As String) As IntPtr

               End Function

               Public Shared Sub LoadNativeAssemblies(ByVal rootApplicationPath As String)
                   Dim nativeBinaryPath = If(IntPtr.Size > 4, Path.Combine(rootApplicationPath, "SqlServerTypes\x64\"), Path.Combine(rootApplicationPath, "SqlServerTypes\x86\"))
                   LoadNativeAssembly(nativeBinaryPath, "msvcr120.dll")
                   LoadNativeAssembly(nativeBinaryPath, "SqlServerSpatial140.dll")
               End Sub

               Private Shared Sub LoadNativeAssembly(ByVal nativeBinaryPath As String, ByVal assemblyName As String)
                   Dim path = System.IO.Path.Combine(nativeBinaryPath, assemblyName)
                   Dim ptr = LoadLibrary(path)

                   If ptr = IntPtr.Zero Then
                       Throw New Exception(String.Format("Error loading {0} (ErrorCode: {1})", assemblyName, Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()))
                   End If
               End Sub
           End Class
       End Namespace
   ```
7. Configuration

In ASP.NET update the web config for Target .NET 4.5.2 (Reporting Services 14.0.0.0)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
      <assemblies>
        <!-- All assemblies updated to version 14.0.0.0. -->
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebDesign, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <!-- Version updated to 14.0.0.0. -->
        <add extension=".rdlc"
          type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpHandlers>
      <!-- Version updated to 14.0.0.0 -->
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*"
        type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"
        validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
      <!-- Version updated to 14.0.0.0 -->
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"
        type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Or [Update Web config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-ver16) for Target .NET 4.6 and above (Reporting Services 15.0.0.0)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6">
      <assemblies>
        <!-- All assemblies updated to version 15.0.0.0. -->
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebDesign, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <!-- Version updated to 15.0.0.0. -->
        <add extension=".rdlc"
          type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6"/>
    <httpHandlers>
      <!-- Version updated to 15.0.0.0 -->
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*"
        type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"
        validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
      <!-- Version updated to 15.0.0.0 -->
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"
        type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

8. Build the solution and confirm the whole project compiles.
9. Upgrade the reports to support the Visual Studio IDE if created in an older version of Visual Studio Report Designer.

Double click the report in Visual Studio and convert when prompted "Do you want to convert this Report". This will automatically update the XML to the current supported schema.

[image: Microsoft Report Designer - Do You Want To Convert This Report?]

When the report has been upgraded, you must click **Save** to finalise the changes to the report file. A backup copy is automatically made of the original file and a new file is created in it's place.

Then when the report is viewed in an XML editor the following schema definition changes will have been made by the conversion tool.

**On a report without report parameters**

***From: VS2013***

```
    <Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" 
            xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
```

***To: VS2019 / VS2022***

```
        <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition" 
                xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

What a Default New VS2019 / VS2022 report uses

```
        <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" 
                xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

**On a report with report parameters**

***From: VS2013***

```
    <Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" 
            xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
```

***To: VS2019 / VS2022***

```
    <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" 
            xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

The conversion tool adds a ***ReportParametersLayout*** block if report has ***ReportParameters*** element. For example;

```
      <ReportParametersLayout>
        <GridLayoutDefinition>
          <NumberOfColumns>1</NumberOfColumns>
          <NumberOfRows>1</NumberOfRows>
          <CellDefinitions>
            <CellDefinition>
              <ColumnIndex>0</ColumnIndex>
              <RowIndex>0</RowIndex>
              <ParameterName>Test</ParameterName>
            </CellDefinition>
          </CellDefinitions>
        </GridLayoutDefinition>
      </ReportParametersLayout>
```

If you click Cancel when prompted to convert the report, there is an option to manually **Edit** the schema.

It is possible to Edit the xml schema and downgrade the supported specification to allow the report to load in the current version of Visual Studio Report Designer.

[image: This version of the report definition language is not supported by this version of Visual Studio Report Designer]

**Downgrade report from 2016 or 2010 to 2008 schema definition**

If the Report was created in a newer unsupported version of the current Report Designer the upgrade will fail. The Report will need to be [downgraded](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/downgrade-report-from-2016-to-2012) for the file to open in Visual Studio 2019.

Please try the following XML markup changes only if the automatic upgrade failed;

***From: 2016 schema***

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" 
        xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

***From: 2016 schema including default font family***

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" 
        xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"
        xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily" 
        MustUnderstand="df">
```

***From: 2010 schema***

```
    <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition" 
            xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

***To: 2008 schema***

```
    <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" 
            xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

Then [Downgrade the SSRS report](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52087498/1165173) by removing elements that are not used in the 2008 schema.

Remove the tag ***ReportSections*** but not any child elements for it

```
<ReportSections></ReportSections>
```

Remove the tag ***ReportSection*** but not any child elements for it

```
<ReportSection></ReportSection>
```

Remove the element ***ReportParametersLayout*** and all child elements (including ***GridLayoutDefinition***)

```
<ReportParametersLayout></ReportParametersLayout>
```

If the [report contains the default font attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38903125/1165173) "df" remove the following also...

Remove the Report **MustUnderstand="df"** attribute if it has one.

Remove the Report **xmlns:df** attribute if it has one.

Remove the element ***df*** and all child elements if it has one.

10. For WinForms - Include file in output directory

If the project is WinForms, to [include the report in the output directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/using-the-winforms-reportviewer-control?view=sql-server-ver16) right click on the Report file and click **Properties**.

Change the file Properties ***Copy To Output Directory*** to "Copy if newer" and Save project.

11. Finally: Build and Test

Once all changes have been saved, build the solution to confirm the project is correctly compiling using the SQL Server Reporting Services runtimes and then test processing an [SSRS Local Report](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1131216/How-to-Run-SSRS-Reports-Locally) using your custom code.

**[Setting up SQL Server native assemblies for spatial data types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41959122/1165173)**

> ASP.NET applications For ASP.NET applications, add the following line
> of code to the Application_Start method in Global.asax.cs:
>
> `SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));`
>
> Desktop applications For desktop applications, add the following line
> of code to run before any spatial operations are performed:
>
> ```
> SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
> ```

**Report Viewer Control Versions**

- 8.0 (2005) - 8.0.50727.42 - Visual Studio 2005
- 9.0 (2008)   - 9.0.30729.1  - Visual Studio 2008
- 10.0 (2010)  - 10.0.40219.1 - Visual Studio 2010
- 11.0 (2012)  - 11.1.3452.0  - Visual Studio 2012/2013
- 12.0 (2014) for SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 - SQL Server 2014
- 12.0 (2015 Report Viewer or using SSDT)  - 12.0.2402.15 - Visual Studio 2015 (SSDT)
- 13.0 for SQL Server 2016 (NuGet) - 13.0.1700.305 - SQL Server 2016
- 13.0 for SQL Server 2016 - 13.0.x.x  - SQL Server 2016 Feature Pack
- 14.0 (NuGet) - 14.0.1016.229 - Visual Studio 2017
- 14.0 (2017 SSDT) - 14.0.x.x - Visual Studio 2017 (SSDT)
- 15.0 (NuGet) - 15.0.1537.0 - Visual Studio 2017/2019/2022
- 15.0 (2017/2019 Report Designer Extension) - 15.0.1322.137 - VS 2017/2019 Report Designer
- 15.0 (2022 Report Designer Extension) - 15.0.1509.0  - VS 2022 Report Designer

Comment: Wow!!! - I have not attempted this, but beyond kind of you to share this - folks, this is how its done!!! - beyond the call of duty here - big up-vote!!!

Answer (score 0):

While creating the report with rdlc file, check the Report Data menu for the parameters. Maybe it is empty. You must fill the parameters used in the report. [image]